# Is there a way to get all the information back? I have no backup

Tags: postgis

By mistake I deleted the public schema and the geometry field was removed from the tables of the other schemas, now I can only see the table and not the vector information, the *geom* information has disappeared

Comment: Make an image of the storage drive now, then google "PostgreSQL data recovery" or something

Comment: How are you inspecting the tables?  In QGIS or some GIS software?  Those won't show the geometry once you've removed the geometry type from the database.  Go into pgadmin and inspect the tables.  The column and data should still be there unless you did a DROP CASCADE.  However, the geometry columns will no longer be defined as the postgis geometry type.  You'll need to create the postgis extension again and then check the geometry columns.  You may also need to alter the type of the geom columns back to geometry.

Comment: Unfortunately, the answer may be to invent a time machine, then go back in time and make a backup prior to the DROP SCHEMA event. Don't forget to destroy the time machine and its plans afterward; those things are dangerous.

Comment: only if your attributes store the coordinates?

Answer (score 0):

And if you create the public schema and reinstall Postgis so that it generates the functions, the projection table and the views that are needed? Another possibility is to create a new database with the postgis extension and take backup of it only the tables and restore them in the new database